# Openlayers 6 - pause rendering

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

How can I pause layer/map rendering in openlayers 6? While scrolling or dragging on map the performance is bad. I would like render my map after only 'moveend'.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can check if `updateWhileAnimating` and `updateWhileInteracting` on your vector layers have been set to `true`. You will get better performance if they are `false` (Default values). See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html
2. Are you using a style cache? This can help performance a lot. See http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch06-styling-vector-layers/example-07.html
3. How many objects are you rendering? Very high numbers will impact performance.
4. What type of object are you rendering? I have seen (and reported) cases where rendering lines with multiple styles can be very slow. Simpler styles helped significantly in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your advice is very usefull for vector layers, but I have tilelayers (more then twenty). Dragging the map is slow after loading tiles.

Answer (score 1):

uses ol/layer/VectorImage for faster rendering during interaction and animations, at the cost of less accurate rendering.
See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/image-vector-layer.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
map.on('movestart', () => {
    layers.forEach(layer => {
        layer.setExtent(map.getView().calculateExtent());
    });
});

map.on('moveend', () => {
    layers.forEach(layer => {
        layer.setExtent(undefined);
    });
});
```